# IIS matches the rule but IIS rewrite module says the rule doesn't match

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, iis, iis-7

I'm having an issue with a rule being applied correctly on my site.

The rule is:

```
(^((?!\/bundles\/).)*[^\/]$)
```

The action is to append a slash to the end of this, using:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" redirectType="Temporary" />
```

I try the following url:

http://example.com:9999/bundles/bundle.js

And IIS redirects me to http://example.com:9999/bundles/bundle.js/

But I go to IIS Manager, go to IIS Rewrite, select this rule, go to test, put the url in, click test, and it says that it's not a match.

If it's not a match, why is it still redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the same rule and it is redirecting. So, it is working as not expected: your rule `(^((?!\/bundles\/).)*[^\/]$)`  **match** to http://example.com:9999/bundles/bundle.js

The problem in your rule. Correct rule is `(^((?!bundles\/).)*[^\/]$)`. I removed slash before `bundles`. Because when request is coming into rule, it is comparing rule with path `bundles/bundle.js` (without starting slash)